# Method#call causes "SecurityError Exception: calling insecure method" in Mustache.rb... why?

Tags: ruby, mustache

Given this method from Mustache.rb [Context#find](https://github.com/defunkt/mustache/blob/master/lib/mustache/context.rb#L123):

```
def find(obj, key, default = nil)
  hash = obj.respond_to?(:has_key?)

  if hash && obj.has_key?(key)
    obj[key]
  elsif hash && obj.has_key?(key.to_s)
    obj[key.to_s]
  elsif !hash && obj.respond_to?(key)
    meth = obj.method(key) rescue proc { obj.send(key) }
    if meth.arity == 1
      meth.to_proc
    else
      meth[]
    end
  else
    default
  end
rescue Exception => e # I added this to give the debugging output below
  debugger
  # ... see debug output below
  raise
end
```

Can anyone explain why I'm getting `SecurityError Exception: calling insecure method: foo_id` given the following:

```
obj               #=> #<MyModel id: 1, foo_id: 3 ...> (an ActiveRecord object)
                  #   Note foo_id is a column in the DB (a method defined by AR)
key               #=> :foo_id
obj.tainted?      #=> false
obj.method(key)   #=> #<Method: MyModel#foo_id>
obj.send(key)     #=> 3
obj.method(key)[] #=> raises "SecurityError Exception: calling insecure method: foo_id"

obj.method(key).tainted? #=> true... WTF?
```

Is there something I should know about `obj.method(key)` and `obj.method(key).call`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this helps but I've been experiencing this in a Rails application and managed to trace it to a bit of code that did `Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(object))`.  It happened that `object` was a hash that contained instances of classes that derived from `ActiveRecord::Base`.  Making the code not serialise those objects solved the error.  Tracking this down was not easy because the errors were reported outside of the callstack of this code, in a completely different request context.

Comment: Ah, very interesting. I've since stripped mustache-rb from my code, so I haven't seen the error in a while...  but thank you for your response.